# What's proper implementation of opIndex?

Tags: d

```
struct A{

  int[3] _data;

  ref int opIndex(size_t i) { return _data[i]; }

  int opIndex(size_t i) const{ return _data[i]; }
}

T fun(T)(const ref T a){

  T ai = a;
  swap(ai[0], ai[1]);  // error
  return ai;
}

immutable A a = A();
immutable A b = fun(a);

void main(){ }
```

The above code gives the following error:

```
Error: ai.opIndex(0LU) is not an lvalue
Error: ai.opIndex(1LU) is not an lvalue
       called from here: fun(a)
```

`ai` is a copy of `a` and it is an lvalue, so I don't understand why I get the error.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `opIndexAssign` instead of opIndex for assignment, so instead of `ref int opIndex(size_t i)` use `int opIndexAssign(int value, size_t i)`.

You can find more here: [Operator Overloading](http://d-programming-language.org/operatoroverloading.html)

**EDIT:**

```
import std.algorithm;

struct A{

  int[3] _data;

  ref int opIndex(size_t i) { return _data[i]; }
}

T fun(T)(){
  T ai;
  // swap(ai._data[0], ai._data[1]);
  swap(ai[0], ai[1]);
  return ai;
}

immutable A a = A();
immutable A b = fun!(A);

void main(){ }
```

Comment: Oh I see, forgot the swap. Seems like you don't get the actual error, try uncommenting the swap and you'll get a new error: `Error: static variable a cannot be referenced at compile time`, this seems to be the actual problem. Furthermore `T ai = a;` gives you an immutable struct.

Comment: ok.  Well, `T ai = a;` shouldn't give an immutable.  Is there anyway to have it not behave that way?

Comment: I am not sure, since you declared `a` as immutable A, which can be also written as ``immutable(A)` (this makes it more obvious, that that's a different type. See the **edit** for a working code, maybe you can also cast the immutable away, but this would also require you to know the actual type.

Comment: It T is not an immutable type `T ai = a;` wont give you an immutable `ai` even if `a` is immutable.

Comment: You can cast away immutability using the Unqual trait: http://www.d-programming-language.org/phobos/std_traits.html#Unqual